# Magnolia dialog size

Tags: magnolia

I have a dialog ( containing a form) with just one field, and I would like to make it as small as possible.
Does anyone know how can I set the size of the dialogue?
At the moment the dialog looks like this[image]

[image]

And I would like something like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the dialogue to non-wide mode?
There is a boolean under dialog definition that you can set 'wide' to 'false'.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

There's an attribute named **wide** which is Boolean.

[Dialog documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Dialog+definition)

By default wide is false, so you could just remove the

> wide: true

attribute in the dialog definition.